# jQuery selector - variable greater than

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a grid system for a jQuery-driven form

I need to add a certain class to all s when the numbers in their class names are greater than or equal to firstNum and secondNum, variables that are in place already.

Each  has a unique class in the format 'firstNumber-secondNumber' e.g. '2-5' or '4-1'

Here's a snippet of the direction I'm looking for - the bit in square brackets will make this a little clearer.

```
$('td.[GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO firstNum]-[GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO secondNum]').addClass('selectable');
```

Any help appreciated - I'm wondering if filtering is the route to go down (?) - but can't quite get there at the moment..!

HTML

```
 <tr> 
     <td class="1-1">cell data</td> 
     <td class="1-2">cell data</td> 
     <td class="1-3">cell data</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
     <td class="2-1">cell data</td> 
     <td class="2-2">cell data</td> 
     <td class="2-3">cell data</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
     <td class="3-1">cell data</td> 
     <td class="3-2">cell data</td> 
     <td class="3-3">cell data</td> 
 </tr>
```

Comment: Yep, you have to use `.filter` and implement the logic yourself. It might be easier though if you store the information differently though, e.g. in `data-*` attributes.

Comment: filtering and parsing the class. Using a class for that might not be the best solution.

Comment: thanks both - @dystroy what would you suggest using rather than a class, out of interest?

Comment: To be sure, can you give an example of your classes and html ?

Comment: I would suggest to use data attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and assuming there is only one class on your `td`, you would do this :

```
$('td').filter(function(){
     var c = this.className;
     if (!c) return false;
     var tokens = c.split('-');
     if (parseInt(tokens[0])>firstNumber
         && tokens.length>0
         && parseInt(tokens[1])>secondNumber
     ) return true;
     return false;
 }).addClass('selectable');
```

But this is heavy. Without knowing the whole context it's hard to make a relevant proposition but data-attributes come to the mind in that case.

---

EDIT, looking at your HTML, you seem to be only interested in the row and cell number. Which means you could do something like this :

```
$('tr:gt('+firstNumber+')').find('td:gt('secondNumber')').addClass('selectable');
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that works great - would be interested to know how data-attributes could improve this and what the ideal solution would be using these...

Comment: using `<td data-a=3 data-b=5>` might be a little cleaner but wouldn't probably make the whole much better. I'm not sure about what to propose.

Comment: I just saw your HTML, maybe what you need is in fact what I just added.

Comment: Thanks again, I did try :gt() originally but ran into problems, I'll look into it though, certainly looks like a more graceful solution.